# How to get Data from table in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm tried to get data from my table using for loop but it occur null point exception.  this is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabel_otapproclInfo.getItems().size(); i++) {
            String s = tabel_otapproclInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getEMPLOYEEID();
            String s2 = tabel_otapproclInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getEMPLOYEENAME();
            String s3 = tabel_otapproclInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getEMPLOYEEDEPT();
            String s4 = tabel_otapproclInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getSTATUS();
            String s5 = tabel_otapproclInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getDATES();
            String u = tabel_otapproclInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getUSERNMAE();

            System.out.println(u + " " + s + " " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s4 + " " + s5);
        }
```

in this code 
tabel_otapproclInfo is table name

this is error is occerd

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ashoklayland.OTApprovelsController.actionApproverlAll(OTApprovelsController.java:126)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'd guess you didn't select anything, so `getSelectedItem()` returns `null`. But your code looks a bit odd anyway - the table should be bound to your model, so why would you need to "scan" the table to know what data it contains? Might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: when tabel_otapproclInfo.getItems().size() it get all the data and remove it from the table. after i tryed to get those data from table it occure this error. i want to get all data from the table but how can it done by not happen null point exception?

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure why you check the size of the `items` list of the table in the loop when you're trying to access the selected element only in the loop body. Note: in case the user didn't select an item `getSelectedItem` returns `null` regardless of the number of items in the table.

Comment: i'll get table size for iterate the table. and run the for loop until the last data had been read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all of the data in a `Table` you should take this approach. In this example, the `Table` object is `Person`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getItems().size(); i++) 
{
    Person tempPerson = table.getItems().get(i);
    System.out.println(tempPerson.getFirstName() + " " + tempPerson.getLastName() + " " + tempPerson.getEmail());
}
```

If you want to get a `Person` from a specific index, where the `index >= 0` and `index < table.getItems().size()`, try:

```
Person tempPerson = table.getItems().get(1);
System.out.println("Specifice index 1: " + tempPerson.getFirstName() + " " + tempPerson.getLastName() + " " + tempPerson.getEmail());
```

If you want to get the `Person` after it has been selected use a listener.

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    System.out.println("On Select: " + newSelection.getFirstName() + " " + newSelection.getLastName() + " " + newSelection.getEmail());
});
```

> Full Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application
{

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
            );

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.getItems().size(); i++) {
            Person tempPerson = table.getItems().get(i);
            System.out.println(tempPerson.getFirstName() + " " + tempPerson.getLastName() + " " + tempPerson.getEmail());
        }

        Person tempPerson = table.getItems().get(1);
        System.out.println("Specifice index 1: " + tempPerson.getFirstName() + " " + tempPerson.getLastName() + " " + tempPerson.getEmail());

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            System.out.println("On Select: " + newSelection.getFirstName() + " " + newSelection.getLastName() + " " + newSelection.getEmail());
        });
    }

    public static class Person
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email)
        {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName)
        {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```